# Etymology of "And the Three Bears"

Tags: etymology, slang, catch-phrases

"*And the three bears*" is a catch-phrase used to express disbelief:-

> This new investment will allow the Government to save taxpayers'
>   money!
>
> *And the three bears.*

Does anyone know how this phrase came to be used in this way? (I can't find any search results without Goldilocks sticking her oar in; I would presume the origin is related to the story, but can't see how.)

Comment: I've never seen it used in a stand-alone sense before.  I suppose it could just be a way of saying "Fairy tale!"

Comment: Perhaps the investment provides long-needed toilet facilities in densely wooded environments thus preventing costly cleanup operations?

Comment: @MarvMills - Actually, it's to answer that eternal question for once and for all.

Comment: Does it also resolve the vexed question of the religious affiliation of the bishop of Rome?

Comment: The concept of the "Goldilocks economy" has been popular for [quite a while](http://myweb.lmu.edu/jdevine/talks/nu3bears.html). It describes an economy that's said to be "just right"—just as Golidlocks likes everything—but with the reminder that Goldilocks basically trashed the house to get this result. Eventually, the three bears are going to return—which symbolizes the inevitable economic backlash that follows bad policy. My guess is that this phrase is a reminder that there will be consequences later.

Comment: This is possibly modelled, perhaps intuitively rather than deliberately, on the phrase **and the rest**.  From [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/and-the-rest): 
PHRASE HUMOROUS

_and (all) the rest (of it)_ PHRASE

used for saying that a number or amount is in fact much higher than someone has said: 
_‘He must be nearly 50.’ _ ‘And the rest!’ I'm sure @Hot Licks gets the meaning right. 'If you're going to tell us a fairy story, at least put in the scary details too.'

Comment: I like the phrase and especially your explanation @ralph.m.  You should post it as an answer.  It gets my vote!

Comment: Can you give us a link to the context where you found this?

Comment: @DJClayworth, it was said to me in ordinary conversation in the office this afternoon, but I have used the expression myself many times.

Comment: Where did you first hear it?

Comment: @DJClayworth, I'm a Hertfordshire boy, so the South-East of England. It has a bit of a schoolboyish ring to it to my ear.

Comment: My take is that the phrase is associating what was just said with a fairy story. You could say "and you shall go to the ball!" or "...and they lived happily ever after." for the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

“….AND THE THREE BEARS stared at Goldilocks in disbelief.”

Perhaps a little tenuous but I can’t think of any other explanation. It would be good to see some other examples of its use.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This is indeed a bit tenuous, but could be made less tenuous by providing a link to the quote.